# Lazy loading in a different way

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I have implemented lazy loading in my site using jQuery plugin. It's pretty awesome. What I am trying to do is loading all the page contents at once.

The problem is when, a user scrolls down to the bottom of the page in the beginning, all the contents are loaded. I want to prevent this. I want to load only the ones which are having kind of focus of the viewer.

Is this possible?

to explain it in a better way, go to this [page](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled.html). Now directly croll down to the bottom of the page. You can observe that all the images are loaded. It's like not implementing the lazy loading at all. When a user scrolls to the bottom at once, the images which are in the midway should not be loaded.

Comment: Hiya man, so to start with checkout this: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload ; Now without any code any person will feel bit stranded to answer your question, also it will be awesome as an ideas if you give an example to illustrate your issue, :) by the way what plugin are you using?

Comment: "using jQuery plugin" - Do you mean the jQuery library, or a plug-in for it?

Comment: im using the same plugin appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload